# Pythonic way to find index of n th occurance of a value in a list?

Tags: python

Here is my list

```
list=[1,2,1,1,1,1,1,4,5]
```

Now i want to know the index of 5th '1' in a pythonic way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[i for (i,e) in enumerate(list) if e==1][5]
```

Answer (score 2):

Enumerate can help here

```
[x for x in enumerate(list) if x[1]==1][5][0]

#X[1]==1  implies values of element equals 1, since x[0] will be enumeration index.
```